# How do Java 8 default methods hеlp with lambdas?

Tags: java

It is claimed in this [article](https://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-method-default-method) that:

> one of the major reasons for introducing `default` methods in
>   interfaces is to enhance the Collections API in Java 8 to support
>   lambda expressions.

I could understand that the `@FunctionalInterface` helped by saying that there is ONLY one abstract method and the lambda should represent this particular method.

But how is it that the `default` methods helped to support lambdas?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To give you an example take the case of the `Collection.forEach` method, which is designed to take an instance of the `Consumer` functional interface and has a default implementation in the `Collection` interface:

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

If the JDK designers didn't introduce the concept of default methods then all the implementing classes of the `Collection` interface would have to implement the `forEach` method so it would be problematic to switch to Java - 8 without breaking your code.

So to facilitate the adoption of lambdas and the use of the new functional interfaces like `Consumer`, `Supplier`, `Predicate`, etc. the JDK designers introduced the concept of default methods to provide backward compatibility and it is now easier to switch to Java - 8 without making any changes.

If you don't like the default implementation in the interface you can override it and supply your own.

Comment: Adding default methods to java interfaces probably did brake existing java code, for example: if a class in java 7 has an int sort() method and also implements Collection, and now there is a default void sort() method in Collection, then the existing class will no longer compile in java 8. I guess that the JDK designers took that into account and chose the best option they had at the time.

Answer (score 16):

They helped indirectly: you can use lambdas on collections thanks to additional methods like `removeIf()`, `stream()`, etc.

Those methods couldn't have been added to collections without completely breaking existing collection implementations if they had not been added as default methods.

Answer (score 4):

Another situation where default methods help a ton is in the functional interfaces themself. Take the [`Function<T,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) interface for example, the only method you really care about is `R apply(T t)`, so when you need a `Function`somewhere, you can pass a lambda and it will create a `Function` instance where that lambda method is the `apply` method.

However once you have a `Function` instance, you can call other useful methods like `<V> Function<T,V> andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)` that combine functions on them. The default implementation is simply chaining the functions, but you can override it if you create your own class implementing the `Function` interface.

In short, default methods give you an easy way to create lambdas from functional interfaces that have additinal methods, while giving you the option to override those additinal methods in with a full class if you need to.

Comment: In that case an abstract class would've achieved the same thing (though removing the opportunity to extend another class).

Comment: I consider this as the most crucial point (At least referring to the quoted statement and question title on a language level - not so much on the (collections) API level) : Namely, that you can have an interface with *multiple* methods, but still "implement" it via a lambda expression if and only if it has a *single abstract method* (in fact, in the beginning, these types had been referred to as "SAM Types" or "Single Abstract Method Types").